# WPF DataGrid binding to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, CustomType>>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

My DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Question.Variations}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Height="97" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,6,0,0" Name="dataGrid1"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variatienr" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="# vraagparameters" 
             Binding="{Binding Value.QuestionParameters.Count}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="# antwoordparameters" 
             Binding="{Binding Path=((TypedFieldsVariation)Value).Answers.Count}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The following column shows nothing except the header:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="# antwoordparameters" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=((TypedFieldsVariation)Value).Answers.Count}"/>
```

I know this is probably wrong, but now my question is how do I show it?

The `itemssource` is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Variation>> Variations`

`Variation` has 2 subclasses, `MultipeChoiceVariation` and `TypedFieldsVariation`

Now I want the property 'Answers' and I'm sure that all the variations in the itemssource for the datagrid are `TypedFieldsVariations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lose the brackets and type casting from the Path it should work:

```
Path=Value.Answers.Count
```

If it doesn't work how you expect then check your Output window for binding errors, it will give you clues as to what has gone wrong. Just make sure that `Count` is a property, not a function.

Comment: @Stef - if you're happy with slugster's answer, click on the "tick" to the left of the answer to mark it as "Accepted". That'll reward slugster **and** you with some reputation points and also indicate to anyone else that this is the *correct* answer. *(You might also want to consider doing the same on some of your other questions as people can be reluctant to provide answers to questions from users who haven't accepted many/any answers)* =)